# VisualSVN - adding from separate Repos?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2010 that exists in one repo. I then want to add a project to this solution from a **separate** repo.

Ive tried right clicking on the solution in VS > Add existing project, but when it adds to the solution, all of the SVN bindings have disappeared in Visual Studio.

Is it possible to add a project from another repo into my current solution? Thanks.
BTW im using VisualSVN / TortoiseSVN.

Comment: While @djechelon below is right, there are cases in which this approach is very helpful; We use such "patchwork" working copies in a few different ways. What you are trying is possible using AnkhSVN.

Comment: Well, I guess you perform checkout and updates automatically, rather having an A4 sheet of paper full of instructions for each developer :)... in that case, it may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`svn:externals`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html) property to pull in part of a separate repository. Note that you lose the ability to commit atomically.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do violates some of the basic SVN usage principles. Each repository is supposed to be an integer and intact source of working code, so when another developer downloads the code he's got everything needed to work (except external dependencies, if any). You seem to be willing to force developers to make a filesystem *puzzle* of projects, that in the general case results in complicated check-outs from several repositories into several folders.

If you want to **make a copy** of a directory from another repository into your repository, I suggest you to do the following:

1. Checkout a copy of the project from the separate repository to a temporary directory
2. With Tortoise, **export** it into a subdirectory of your solution
3. Add it to VisualSVN, and then be prepared to commit all the files into your repo as a copy

Remember, once the separate repository is updated, updated **won't be reflected** on your repo. You'll have to make patches or better use `merge` command.

Comment: No i dont want to make a copy of one directory from another repo into another, i want a visual studio solution that contains projects from different repo.